# First three nonzero terms in series solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Problem:

Find the first three nonzero terms in series solution of the problem

$y''(x) + (cosx)y = 0 , y(0) = 1$

As I moved on with the solution of this question, in every iteration something kept contributing to the first terms. It is pretty sure that I am doing something critically wrong, however couldn't find it out. If you can help me I will really appreciate it. (I was going to add what I have done, but since it seems gibberish, I decided not to.)

Comment: What about $y'(0)$?  We need at *two* initial datum, right?

Comment: @RobertLewis unfortunately only $y(0)=1$ is given in the question, nothing about $y'$ :/

Comment: Since you only have one condition for a second order differential equation, there will be one arbitrary constant and you need to express each coefficient as a function of it.

Comment: Are you requested to use Picard iteration or can you just plug in the power series for $y(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+...$? Since zero terms seem to be expected, perhaps one is to find a symmetric solutions, i.e., $y'(0)=0$.

Comment: @LutzL just plugging in the power series should be enough I think.

Comment: Keep $y'(0)$ undetermined.